# Mapping of $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> What happens to the angles at the origin under the mapping $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$ when a) $\alpha>1$ b) for $0<\alpha<1$ ($z\in\mathbb{C}$)?

I know that the angles increases resp. decreases but I am unable to show why.

I've tried rewriting the mapping using the parametrization $z(t)$ where $t_0=z_0$.
And since the angle is given by the derivative the angle of the mapping is:
$$arg\Big(f'(z(t_0))\Big)=arg\Big( f'(z(t))z'(t)\Big)=arg(f'(z(t)))+arg(z'(t)).$$

At $t=0$ the second term is zero but what about the first term? Is it correct to say:

$$arg(\alpha z^{\alpha -1}(0))=arg(\alpha)+0?$$

If this is true then I don't know why the origin would be anymore interseting than any other point since the same relation (i.e. $arg(\alpha)+arg(z(t)^{\alpha - 1})$ is true whenever.

Comment: if you replace $z$ with $r e^{it}$, $r > 0, t \in [c,c+2\pi[$, you  can define explicitly $f$ as $f(re^{it}) = r^\alpha e^{it \alpha}$, and see how $c$ is the problem (representing the branch of the logarithm that you chose)